# How do I use routing in react application to open a particular page of an already existing flex application?

Tags: reactjs, flash, apache-flex, routes, react-router

I'm creating a web application using React that in turn routes to open an already existing Flex application. When I try to achieve this routing I'm able to navigate to the flex application but it doesn't load the particular required page of it but it loads the homepage of the application. How do I achieve the routing from React application to the required particular page of the Flex and Flash application?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could route to the Flex app and add a parameter to the URL.

Routing to `https://.../route/to/flex?pageId=something`
then in the Flex app you can use

`var pageIdToOpen:String = HTTPUtil.getParameterValue('pageId');`

and do what's needed. You can even send a few more parameters if you need to have some values...